# How to use the Comparator method in my project

Tags: java, priority-queue

I am creating an issue tracker in Java.I have an issue class as follows:

```
import java.util.Date;
public class Issue {

    int IssueNo;
    String IssueTitle;
    String text;
    Date TimeStamp=new Date();
    String Creator;
    String Assignee;
    String tag;
    int priority;
    String status;

}
```

My program has to display the issues based on either the priority(a number from 1 to 9) or TimeStamp(date on which issue is created).I want to know how to use priority queue and comparator to display the issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comparator has one method:

```
int compareTo(T a, T b)
```

where returning a negative int means a is bigger, a positive int means b is bigger, and 0 means equal

So for doing multi-factor comparisons (as you are doing), start with priority.

```
int priorityCompare = ((Issue)b).priority - ((Issue)a).priority;
```

if priorityCompare is not 0, return priorityCompare. If it is 0, then move onto the next point of comparison (date) and so on until you've found a comparison point that differs, or all points are equal, in which case return 0;

Comment: Understanding concepts is important, but learners should be directed toward `Comparator.comparingInt(Issue::getPriority).thenComparing(Issue:getTimeStamp)`.

Comment: The scenario is users can filter the issues based on priority or on date created.There will be two check boxes "prioirty" and "date".If they choose priority then issues should be displayed based on priority.If they choose date,issues should be displayed based on date

Comment: @SaadHamim it sounds like using a RadioButton instead of a checkbox would make more sense design-wise. But you'd want to use a comparator that compares by priority when priority is checked, and one that uses date when date is checked

Comment: thank you!I am new to data structure and now i realised(thanks to you) that i can create mutliple comparator classes and pass it to my priority queue